# AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'shapesize' on line 14

Tags: python, object, import, attributes, attributeerror

I'm trying to make a turtle game on Repl.it and I don't know why this error keeps coming up. Here is my code:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("white")
wn.setup(width=800, height=800)
wn.tracer(0)

# Set up the ground

ground = turtle.Turtle()
ground.color("white")
ground.shape("square")
ground.speed(0)
ground.shapesize(stretch_wid=200, stretch_len=20)
ground.speed(0)
ground.color("black")
ground.penup()
ground.goto(0, -400)
ground.direction = "stop"
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the implementation of the turtle library on repl.it is somewhat limited and not all commands are available. You can either run it locally to use all commands or remove incompatible commands.

Source:  https://repl.it/talk/ask/Turtle-python-resizing/7312

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a way to do this.
Whenever you create a new repl instead of creating a "python with turtle" repl just create a normal python one. Then import the turtle module and it should work. When importing it on a basic python file it imports everything.
Whenever you do `import turtle` it is also a good idea to add `from turtle import *` that way you import everything.

Answer (score -1):

I also had this problem
You can use Python with pygame instead of python with turtle because for some reason, it works

Comment: Pygame is a entirely different library and not compatible with turtle