# Shapesize code wouldn't work for some reason

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I tried to do something very similar from some other code but it didn't work even though i thought i did right thing. Also i tried copy pasting the whole code in **trinket.io** to find out that maybe it was in another version, i want to make a 3D rolling ball or something...
error message:

AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'shapesize' on line 25 in main.py

Code:

```
import turtle as trtl

di = trtl.Turtle()

di.penup()
screen = trtl.Screen()
x = 0
def go_left():
  global x
  x -= 5
  di.goto(x,-190)

def go_right():
  global x
  x += 5
  di.goto(x,-190)

screen.onkey(go_left, 'left')
screen.onkey(go_right, 'right')
t = 1
di.shape("circle")
def go_forward():
  global t
  t -= 5
  di.shapesize(t) #error
screen.onkey(go_forward, 'up')
screen.listen()
def go_backward():
  global t
  t += 5
  di.shapesize(t) #error
screen.onkey(go_backward, 'down')
```

Comment: `t -+ 5`.  I'm guessing you mean to use `-=` instead of `-+` :-)

Comment: oh your right but that also wasn't the error message but you have a point so ill have to change that

Comment: Are you using repl.it, by chance?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60961758/attributeerror-turtle-object-has-no-attribute-shapesize-on-line-14

Comment: Nope, i'm using trinket.io i should make it more clear

Comment: I use repl.it. I also get the same error.